# Instrumentation box, digital input signal conditioning

Tags: digital-logic, signal, filtering

I'm designing an instrumentation box with opto-coupled digital inputs (BNC). For better noise/ground loops immunity/signal reflections I added 50 ohm resistors and 1n filtering capacitor (if needed). I can also make GND1 floating or earth grounded, using a jumper(not shown) if I run into problems in practice. Input signal switching is <10kHz

What is your opinion?

[image: scrible]

Comment: opinion based questions are off topic here ... please ask a question relating to electronics design

Comment: It's better to have specs on performance than a rough idea.  Can you imagine everything that can interfere with your expectations?  If not , then you aren't ready.